# How to create keyclock clientSecret via API

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect

I’m using keycloak version 20.0.2, and I want to know if it possible to create clientSecret through a post request (/admin/realms/:realm/clients/:id/client-secret).

I want to send body to post request with my own generated client secret value

```
https://{host}/admin/realms/{realm}/clients/{id}/client-secret

Body: {  
   "clientSecret":"my own generated value here"  
}

Response: {  
  type: "secret",  
  value: "my own generated value here" 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.

#1 One is create new client API with own secret

#2 Second is can random generated secret on existing client by Keycloak

But no option update the client secrete with your own.

#### #1 One is create new client API with own secret

```
POST {Keycloak URL}/admin/realms/test/clients
```

Body

```
{
    "clientId": <new client ID>,
    "name": <Cleint Name>,
    "enabled": true,
    "clientAuthenticatorType": "client-secret",
    "secret": <my-own-secret>
}
```

Example by Postman
[image]

In Body

```
{
    "clientId": "Test-Client",
    "name": "Test-Client-New",
    "enabled": true,
    "clientAuthenticatorType": "client-secret",
    "secret": "my-new-own-secret"
}
```

Result
[image]
[image]

#### #2 Second is can random generated secret by Keycloak

```
POST {Keycloak URL}/admin/realms/{my-realm}/clients/{client-uuid}/client-secret
```

Input Body

```
None
```

Response Body

```
{
    "type": "secret",
    "value": <Random created new secret by Keycloak>
}
```

[image]
[image]

Result in Keycloak UI
[image]